# How to break while loop in an inner for loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, break

`while` doesn't break when i>10 in for loop:

```
i = 0
x = 100
while i<=10:
    for a in xrange(1, x+1):
        print "ok"
        i+=1
```

and it prints `"ok"` 100 times. How to break the `while` loop when `i` reaches 10 in `for` loop?

Comment: Just throw it in a function and return out of the inner loop.

Comment: Why do you use =< instead of <=? Is this a typo or has this a specific function?

Comment: @sshannin could you be more specific?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Until the inner loop "returns", the condition in the outer loop will never be re-examined. If you need this check to happen every time after `i` changes, do this instead:

```
while i<=10:
    for a in xrange(1, x+1):
        print "ok"
        i+=1
        if i > 10:
            break
```

That `break` will only exit the inner loop, but since the outer loop condition will evaluate to `False`, it will exit that too.

Comment: Just be sure not to add anything after the for loop or that will execute after the inner loop breaks.

Comment: @Matt Briançon Yes?? I thought `while` will break as soon as `for` breaks?

Comment: @alwbtc `while` won't break unless either of these happens: a) you call `break` while in its body (strictly in its body, not in the loops inside it); b) the body finished executing, and the condition evaluates to `False`; c) you call `continue` while in its body (strictly, also) and the condition evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 8):

```
i = 0
x = 100
def do_my_loops():
  while i<=10:
    for a in xrange(1, x+1):
      print "ok"
      i+=1
      if time_to_break:
        return
do_my_loops()
```

where `time_to_break` is the condition you're checking.

Or in general:

```
def loop_container():
  outer_loop:
    inner_loop:
      if done:
        return

loop_container()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the outer loop's condition won't be checked until the inner loop finishes - and at this point `i` is already 100. From my perspective, the correct way to write this and get the desired output would be to put a guard inside the inner loop and break it when `i` reaches 10.

```
for a in xrange(1, x+1):
    if i < 10:
        print "ok"
        i+=1
    else:
        break
```

If there is some other reason why you want to break an outer loop while you're inside the inner loop, maybe you should let us in on the details to better understand it.

Answer (score -1):

What about this?

```
x = True 
while x:
    for i in range(20):
        if i>5:
            x = False
            break
        else:
            print(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
booked = False
for i in range(100, 200):
    if booked:
        break
    while True:
        for x in range(1, 3):
            if booked:
                break
            result = 0
            if result == 1:
                booked = True
        break
    continue
```